# When I open fancybox after submit form my form fills 100% of the width and 100% of the height

Tags: wordpress, fancybox, contact-form-7

My fancybox version is 1.5.8.2.

After sending the form, I did close, and when open thereafter without page refresh my form  fills 100% of the width and 100% of the height.
Before my form looked good.

After submit my form looks like:

[image: http://prnt.sc/eh61lh]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the page in question? It's most likely a CSS issue.

Comment: http://client.it-kitchen.com.ua/katana/%E3%81%8A%E5%95%8F%E3%81%84%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B/